# Get environment variable defined in Linux bash to webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have checked out tons of SO questions about "environment variables in webpack" using e.g. the DefinePlugin:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({'ENV': JSON.stringify('staging')})
```

but I cannot for the life of me find a way to inject an environment variable defined in the linux bash shell, instead of using the hard coded `staging` string

In my production and staging environements I have variables such as `$ENV` and `$API_KEY` defined, and I want to use their values in my webpack / ReactJs code.

**Edit**

I notice, if I run the a webpack command from cli:

```
 $ ENVIRONMENT=staging
 $ node_modules/.bin/webpack -p
```

And in my webpack.config.js file defines

```
 new webpack.DefinePlugin({'ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.ENVIRONMENT)})
```

This does not work (ENV is undefined in my JS code),

However, if I run it on the same line, it seems to work - ENVIRONMENT seems to be available in the webpack.config.js file:

```
$ ENVIRONMENT=staging node_modules/.bin/webpack -p
```

So I would really like to make this work without having to define the ENVIRONMENT variable on the same line as the webpack command.

Comment: Using `process.env.$ENV`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `nodejs` you can get your environment variables via `process.env` object. In your case you can do `process.env.$ENV` and `process.env.$API_KEY` to get `$ENV` and `$API_KEY` env vars respectively.

Comment: For me, the `$` character was interfering. This worked: `process.env.FOO`, rather than `process.env.$FOO`. This was from within a `webpack.config.js` file.

Answer (score 2):

Stupid me forgot to export the variable in the bash terminal

```
$ export ENVIRONMENT=staging 
$ node_modules/.bin/webpack -p
```

works fine and, as pointed out, one can then access the ENVIRONMENT variable with `process.env.ENVIRONMENT` from inside *webpack.config.js*